# Measure / Remove H.264 Video Delay

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, h.264

I have an IP camera that sends an H.264 video stream that is supposed to be mixed / muxed with a separate audio stream.

On direct mixing

```
ffmpeg -i <video> -i <audio> -map 0:v -map 1:a <output>
```

there appears to be a big audio/video delay of up to several seconds. I would like to eliminate that as good as feasible.

I can somehow do that manually ([`-itsoffset`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options)) by bisecting with try and error BUT (apart from that this is awkward and cumbersome) the offset seems to vary. We have some good and bad (offset >= 1 s) recordings from the same day using the same setup the same way.

The audio processing beforehand is all analogue and should therefore have a negligible input delay.

---

The offset seems to at least result from two places:

1. The encoding + transportation (about half a second when viewing the stream directly [compare e.g. hand waving])
2. ffmpeg mixing itself (the ffmpeg output has an even higher audio-video offset)

---

#### Regarding 1

Is there a way to programmatically approximate the a priori video delay?

The muxing computer as well as the camera run an NTP client so that their clocks could be seen as coherent.

If I could deduce the cameras system time from the H.264 meta data fields, I would directly get the offset by subtracting the local time. I stumbled about [PCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream#PCR) and [PTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_timestamp) (add. [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5c05/84bf06c3dfe90c023c86f862d94bc6d319de.pdf)) but my knowledge about H.264 is too shallow.

#### Regarding 2

What causes the additional offset?

---

### Edit

The actual full ffmpeg command is:

```
ffmpeg
    -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 \
    -fflags +genpts         \
    -max_delay 2000000      \
    -thread_queue_size 1024 \
    -i <rtsp-video>         \
    -max_delay 2000000      \
    -thread_queue_size 1024 \
    -itsoffset <audio-offset> \
    -f pulse                \
    -i <audio-device>       \
    -af "aresample=async=1" \
    -codec:a aac            \
    -b:a 384k               \
    -ar 48000               \
    -vcodec copy            \
    -tune zerolatency       \
    -map 0:v -map 1:a       \
    -max_muxing_queue_size 99999 \
    -f flv                  \
    -y                      \
    <output>
```

Additionally, I found [openRTSP](http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/) (`livemedia-utils` on Debian, `live-media` on Arch) that fetches a parameter `o` (e.g. `o=- 1599320926814396`) that corresponds well to the cameras UTC system time in microseconds as displayed also in the web-interface. I take that as promising start for further investigations.

E.g.

```bsh
    $ date -d@$( echo $(openRTSP -r rtsp://109.98.78.106 2>&1 | grep -Po '(?<=o=-\s)\d+' | head -n1 ) / 1000000 | bc )
    Sat Sep  5 05:48:46 PM CEST 2020
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 1, the answer is that the H.264 *video* bit stream does not contain usable timestamp information.  Any of that would be in the *transport* RTSP (RTP) packets.  For more information about this, see the answers to the following question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149983/h-264-rtsp-absolute-timestamp

This might let you figure out something in a semi-automated way.

Regarding 2, `ffmpeg` is going to pick up the RTSP stream at a random point and the video would not be decodable until it gets an I picture.  I don't know how `ffmpeg` does the bit stream repackaging but wouldn't be surprised if there's some RTP packets being discarded at the start of the stream until there is a sync point.

Not sure of your use case, but if you are looking to take audio from a mixer and live-stream video using a cheap IP camera, this would be just the start of a world of pain.

Comment: Thank you for the RTP hint! It's indeed an RTSP stream. I'll dig into that. Could you elaborate a bit more on the _world of pain_? The camera hasn't been that cheap. :)

Comment: Do you know why bi-directional predictions introduces a delay? I would naturally expect the audio to buffer as long as the predictions are being calculated.

Comment: I meant that bi-directional prediction introduces a delay in the video bit stream since several frames (maybe around half a second depending on frame rate) are stored in a buffer while prediction is calculated.  But you're right that this should not itself cause a sync issue, and any offset should be more-or-less constant.  Can you edit the question to show what `ffmpeg` command you're using to mux?

Comment: I added the full command above minus the logging options. Apparently it already used the zerolatency setting.

Comment: You're using `-vcodec copy` so there's no video encoding being done anyway and `zerolatency` should have no effect.  I didn't dig into it, but most likely `ffmpeg` will wait for an I-frame from the camera in order to start repackaging the stream.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else stumbling upon this post: I ended up with the following (that kind of works):

1. Setup local ntp server on the recording computer
2. Set the cameras ntp client to the recording computers ntp server and set it to sync regularly
3. The difference of the system time of the recording computer and the timestaps of the RTP stream gives you a rough estimate of the transit time of the packages.
4. Do this once before the recording and use this offset to calculate a value to plug in to ffmpeg as offset.